# Why was this answer converted into a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, comments

About an hour ago, an answer was posted to [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/48205/39658) by a 1-rep user. It wasn't the best answer, but to me it clearly *was* an attempt at answering the question. While it referenced [the existing answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/48206/39658), it only did so to say "that answer is wrong" before launching into an answer of its own.

Nonetheless, it's now been converted into [a comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/48205/did-pakistan-lose-each-and-every-war-it-fought-with-india-from-1947-to-1999/48214#comment223866_48206) on that answer. What's more, since it was too long to fit inside a single comment, it now cuts off awkwardly halfway through:

[image]

I have no idea why this was done. Regardless of its quality as an answer, it was clearly intended to *be* an answer, not a comment. If anything, it should have been deleted altogether (I'll note that the same user's first attempt at answering that question was deleted within 20 minutes of being posted).

**Why was this answer converted into a comment?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrasing the question: "Did Pakistan lose every war with India, 1947-1999?"

Paraphrasing the main answer : "There were four wars. Pakistan didn't achieve its goals in any, so effectively, yes, but they didn't unconditionally surrender."

Paraphrasing the two attempts made by the one user, in now-deleted answers: "That answer is wrong. Here are examples where Pakistan lost, including one example of surrender."

Saying another answer is wrong, with reasons, belongs in a comment on the answer. Listing some occasions where Pakistan lost (without showing it is exhaustive) doesn't address the question. You must either show exhaustively that Pakistan always lost or give an example where Pakistan did not lose.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: I think the important part is your last sentence. The post was answering whether Pakistan has lost any single war with India, rather than *every* war.